# finding Laplace transform of $\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{t})$

Tags: laplace-transform, error-function

I am trying to show that the Laplace transform of erf(√(t)) is equal to 1/(s√(s+1))

I have started with the definition of erf(t) as (2/√)times the integral from t-0 of e^(-x^2) and substituted √(t) for t.  I then used a Taylor series for e^(-x^2) and took the Laplace transform of that.  I'm left with a series I don't know what to do with as I don't see a direct route to what I'm trying to get to: 1/(s√(s+1)).  Am I even on the right track?  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(s)$ be the Laplace transform of erf$(\sqrt{t})$:

$$f(s)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}dt\,e^{-st}\int_0^\sqrt{t}dx\,e^{-x^2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\int_\Omega dtdx\, e^{-x^2-st}\,,$$

where $\Omega$ is the region in the first quadrant of the $x$-$t$ plane bounded by the curve $t=x^2$ and the (vertical) $t$ axis. Interchanging the order of the integrals, i.e. doing first the integral in $t$ and then the integral in $x$, one gets:

$$f(s)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}dx\,e^{-x^2}\int_{x^2}^{+\infty}dt\,e^{-st} =
\frac{2}{s\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}dx\,e^{-(s+1)x^2} = \frac{1}{s\sqrt{s+1}}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you so much.